# Recursively reversing a linkedlist

Tags: java, recursion, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a LinkedList using recursive calls, please let me know where I'm going wrong, I'm not able to catch reversed LL head.
LLNode is a linkedlist node and ReverseLLRecursively.reverse is the function I wrote for reversing.

Here is my code:

```
public class LLNode {
    private int data;
    private LLNode next;

    public LLNode(int data, LLNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public LLNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LLNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data + "->[" + (next!=null?next.data:"") + "]";
    }
}

public class ReverseLLRecursively {

    public static LLNode newHead = new LLNode(-1, null);

    public static LLNode reverse(LLNode head, LLNode newHead) {
        if(head==null || head.getNext()==null) {
            newHead = head;
            return head;
        }

        LLNode node = reverse(head.getNext(), newHead);
        node.setNext(head);
        head.setNext(null);
        return node.getNext();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LLNode ll = new LLNode(1,new LLNode(2, new LLNode(3,  new LLNode(3, new LLNode(2,  new LLNode(3, null))))));

        reverse(ll , newHead);
        System.out.println(newHead);

    }

}
```

Comment: I know there are ready solutions available on web to reverse a LL recursively. But that wont help me understand where did I go wrong in recursion.

Comment: You are trying to do to much stuff and end up doing everything wrong. You have 2 mechanisms in place. Both are not working. You just need 1, which is the returnValue of reverse(ll); I have a static and non-static version in my answer, compare them to yours and look at the difference (altough my version is somewhat self-explanatory because it's properly names). Also learn to properly name stuff, all your names and variables are abused and cause you to not understand your own code.

Comment: just rename your method variable: public static LLNode reverse(LLNode head, LLNode **newHead**) and then LLNode node = reverse(head.getNext(), **newHead**);    This will work.

Comment: @Tunaki, I was not looking for solution to reverse a Linkedlist, but issue in my approach. Why is it still marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating your problem and work with a local variable which has the same name as a static member. This should be simpler:

```
public static LLNode reverse(LLNode previous) {
    if(previous==null) {
        return null;
    }
    LLNode toReturn = (previous->getNext() == null) ? previous : reverse(previous.getNext());
    previous.getNext().setNext(previous);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Note, that toReturn will be the new head.

Comment: Getting nullpointer exception.

Comment: @user2725673, yes, I returned previous.getNext() if previous->getNext() was null mistakenly instead of previous. Please, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Making the reverse a method of LLNode, makes stuff somewhat easier.

You want to return the last value (and only the last) in your linked list. If you have it, return, otherwise go deeper until you have it. After you have the end, store it, setNext as you don't need the value of next anymore, return the end.

```
public LLNode reverse(LLNode previous) {
    if(getNext()==null) {
        setNext(previous);
        return this;
    }
    LLNode returnValue = getNext().reverse(this);
    setNext(previous);
    return returnValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        LLNode ll = new LLNode(1,new LLNode(2, new LLNode(3,  new LLNode(3, new LLNode(2,  new LLNode(3, null))))));

        ll = ll.reverse(null);
        System.out.println(ll);

}
```

Otherwise the static variant if you need it for whatever reason.

```
public static LLNode reverse(LLNode current) {
    if(current.getNext()==null) {
        return current;
    }
    LLNode returnValue = reverse(current.getNext());
    current.getNext().setNext(current);
    current.setNext(null);
    return returnValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        LLNode ll = new LLNode(1,new LLNode(2, new LLNode(3,  new LLNode(3, new LLNode(2,  new LLNode(3, null))))));

        ll = reverse(ll);
        System.out.println(ll);

}
```